# Shared Preference in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an Error in getting Shared Preference.....

My Code is...

```
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

  String iddoc = "";

  getStartVal() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      iddoc = prefs.getString("doctorId");
    });

  if(iddoc == null){
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
      )); 
      
    }else{
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()),
      ));  
    }

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getStartVal();
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: RadialGradient(
                      colors: [HexColor("#cc1076"), HexColor("#ff72be")]),
                ),
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        radius: 50.0,
                        child: Image(image: AssetImage('images/logo.png'),),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "OMIS Doc",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 24.0),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Please wait.....",
                      softWrap: true,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And my Output is....

'data != null a non-null string must be provided to a text widget'

Waht I need is to check wheather there is any shared preference with the same key using if condition to go to next page......

But in my code it is showing error.....

Why it is Showing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this must have been coming from another part of your code

> data != null a non-null string must be provided to a text widget

there you need to basically do the below

```
Text(yourText ?? '')
```